# firestore セキュリティルールのエラー

Tags: firebase

当初以下のように設定していました。これならエラーは出ないのですが、match /{document=**} の部分ですべてのドキュメントのreadを許可しているので脆弱だというメッセージをもらい、変更を検討。

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read : if true
    }

    match /users/{usersID} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == usersID
    }
    match /posts/{postsID} {
      allow write: if 'users/' + request.auth.uid != request.resource.data.user_id
    }
    
  }
}
```

そこでいったん以下のように変更しましたが、エラーとなりクライアント側からアクセスできなくなりました。

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{usersID} {
        allow read ;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == usersID
    }
    match /posts/{postsID} {
        allow read ;
      allow write: if 'users/' + request.auth.uid != request.resource.data.user_id
    }
    
  }
}
```

`Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

両者の設定でやっていることは同じに思えるので、エラーの理由が不明です。
詳しい方、思い当たる原因を教えていただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

**※セキュリティ関連のトピックであり、注意が必要な内容を含みます。必ずご自身で確認・検証してください。**

恐らく、読み取りを許可していない階層に読み取り対象があるのだと思われます。

<strike>変更後のread権限の書き方にミスがあります。
アクセスできないのはそれが原因だと思います。
元の書き方と見比べてみてください。</strike>

※勘違いでした。申し訳ない。

ただし、個人情報などを含むデータに対して元の書き方をすると、全世界に対して読み取りの許可をした状態になります。適切な権限の設定が必要です。
どのデータがprivateで、どのデータがpublicなのか切り分けが必要だと思われます。

firebaseはかなり自由度が高いので、難しく考えるよりは、階層構造そのものをprivateとpublicに分け、データを完全に分離するという手もあります。これはprivateゾーンでは本人のみアクセス可能、publicゾーンでは誰でもアクセス可能という権限を設定し、その権限に沿ったデータを格納するだけですが、簡単かつ堅牢です。

Comment: 「allow read ;」の部分を 「allow read : if true」に変更しましたが結果が変わりませんでした。
原因を

ご指摘いただいた通り、階層ごとにprivateとpublicを分けようとしていたところで、いったん各階層の読み込みをtrueにして動作を確かめ、それから細かい権限設定をしていこうと考えていました。

Comment: 結果が変わらなかったということであれば、何か定義していない場所に読み込もうとしているものがあるのだと思います。usersやposts直下以外に読み取り対象があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 例えばなのですが、posts直下などよりもっと深い階層に何かデータがあったりすると、ルールを任意の深い階層に適用するための再帰ワイルドカード構文（末尾が{name=**}という形式）を使うか、対象そのものを別のmatchステートメントなどで追加する必要があります。

Comment: おっと。すみません。先程手元で確認して気づいたのですが、「allow read;」という書き方でもtrue扱いで動きますね。普段この書き方はしないので勘違いしていたようです。後で見た方がfalse扱いになると勘違いするとマズイので、念の為回答を修正させていただきます。